# How to access my Home PC from the office?

Tags: remote-desktop, file-sharing

At the office I'm working behind a proxy. Is there any way to access my home computer, or just files shared there from my office?

Answer (score 8):

[LogMeIn](http://logmein.com).

The free version doesn't have file transfers though, but then you can always use something like [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) for that.

Comment: But is that free? Isn't there an alternative?

Comment: There's a limited free version with which you can remote control your machine at home. What else do you need ;-)

Comment: Here's the free one, it's hidden a bit: https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/register.asp you can add any number of PCs, and it tunnels through proxies I think via HTTP or something on port 80, but not certain

Comment: Careful though, LogMeIn will want you to "try" the pro version on first install. Not much of a problem, but you will get "reminders" during a month, to upgrade.

Comment: I've been using LogMeIn Free for a couple years now and it's great.  The free version is missing the capability to transfer files between the remote computer and the local computer, though.  But I've been able to work around that so far.

Answer (score 2):

**Sharing/sync files**

Microsoft Live Mesh

- [http://www.mesh.com](https://www.mesh.com)

**Remote Desktop**

Team Viewer

- http://www.teamviewer.com

Comment: I use Mesh. Gets through all firewalls and allows me to store files in the cloud if I want

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **[TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com)**.

The client (that you would run on your work machine) can be configured to access the Internet through a proxy.

Comment: This one also supports file transfers and there is a phone version for it too.

Answer (score 1):

If its just about sharing files freely between two points.

[**SugarSync**](https://www.sugarsync.com/) give a couple of GB storage and sync

You could also use Unite.Opera but I don't think its stable enough yet.