# Getting my IP address?

Tags: ip-address, dynamic-ip

My system has a dynamic shared IP provided to me by my ISP. I want to give my IP address to a friend so she can allow access to her server for requests coming from my IP.

Can someone please tell me how I can find a static IP address to give to her?

Thanks a lot for any help...

Comment: You probably don't have a static IP address.  Most ISPs give you a new IP at least every few weeks because they don't want people running web servers from their homes.  They want you to pay for higher tier service if you want to do that (for a fee you can get a static IP address).  Look into DynDNS or No-IP as suggested in some of the answers.

Comment: Actually, I'd love to pay more **for a dynamic** IP address. My (high quality) provider only uses static addresses, but the privacy issues bother me a bit.

Comment: Getting your IP is easy. http://ipkoala.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might also be interested in [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com).
Look at [**How to access my Home PC from the office?**](https://superuser.com/questions/17911/how-to-access-my-home-pc-from-the-office)

Answer (score 7):

[www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/)

I recommend also using [www.no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com/) where you can pick an alias like, myserver.no-ip.org, install software which will look at your ip and update it accordingly. That way you can just give your fiends etc myserver.no-ip.org as address and the software will update the ip when it changes.

Comment: For a quick, one-off case, whatismyip.com does the job, but for a longer-term solution DynDNS or a similar service is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please tell me how I can find a static IP address to give to her?

Using the proposed things like [DynDNS.com](http://www.dyndns.com/) will give you a "static" host name, but not a static IP address. If that friend really needs to know an IP address for the filtering then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

[No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/) and [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) provide host names which can be updated whenever your IP address changes.  Both provide update clients and most routers natively support one or more Dynamic DNS providers.

Here is a [list of other dynamic DNS providers](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/Protocols/DNS/DNS_Providers/Dynamic_DNS/).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.whatismyip.com will give you the "public" IP address of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this place: [What is my IP address?](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get both [your ip addresses](http://tejji.com/ip/my-ip-address.aspx) here. It shows internal as well as external ip address.

Comment: How could a website see my internal IP address? I don't believe that is possible.