# changing the router to access my webserver

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, webserver

I am trying to build my first website, and I'd like to host it in a Raspberry Pi. I am using a mobile broadband connection with a 4G router ([Vodafone R216-Z 4G WiFi](http://www.4gltemall.com/vodafone-r216-z-4g-mobile-wifi-hotspot.html)). I [was told](https://superuser.com/questions/1154540/configuring-my-laptop-to-serve-a-website-through-openssh/1154543?noredirect=1#comment1662294_1154543) I cannot access my webserver because my ISP won't allow it.

This question is to ask whether simply changing my router would solve my problem, rather than changing ISP as I just bought a one-yera rechargeable sim unfortunately. If so, could you please reccomend how should I choose my router? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can successfully port forward port 80 at minimum to your webserver (behind the router) you ought to be able to host a webserver.

If your current router allows you to do this but it still doesn't work, then the ISP is probably blocking the forward and a new router likely won't help.