# cannot access my web server after setting up a DMZ with my mobile broadband router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, dmz

I am trying to open my web server to the internet in order to give some friends a view on my on-development websites. Since I gave up trying with the [port forward way](https://superuser.com/questions/1154540/configuring-my-laptop-to-serve-a-website-through-openssh) (my ISP is probably not allowing this with my router), I started thinking about DMZ.

So, I added my internal server IP in the DMZ setting of my router (see image below), and now I'd like to test the connectivity using my windows phone (as I don't have another computer at the moment). Still, using the browser and inserting the same internal IP (something like "192.168.X.X") does not seem to work (I get "Cannot visualize the page" message). Is it just because I am using a smartphone? Am I supposed to access my web server with a different URL (e.g. by including port 80)?

I confirm my Apache service is on and that I can reach the websites from within my LAN. Is there anything else I am still missing? I am aware about the troubles of using DMZ, but it's fine since it's just a temporary experiment for me.

My router is a [Vodafone r216z](http://www.vodafone.com/content/index/what/devices/vodafone-r216-z.html).

[image: DMZ configuration]

**EDIT 1**

I am now trying to access the web server from the external device by typing the external IP of the server machine (found with [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/)) via browser from the smartphone, but still the same result. The URL is like "/tutorial/ajaxdemo.html". Also, if this is of any interest, the firewall is down for the web server server ports...

Comment: You need to use the public IP address.

Comment: where? in the DMZ settings or when accessing from the browser from the external device?

Comment: In the browser from the external device.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it's still not working... I read the IP from whatismyip.com and used that from the browser. Just to clarify a few things: the web server is on and if I access the page from the server machine itself by typing (e.g.) "localhost/tutorial/ajaxdemo.html" I reach the resource. When I do the same by using "<EXTERNAL_SERVER_IP>" instead of the "localhost" part, it cannot reach the page. Any suggestion?

Comment: Nothing else springs to mind at the moment.

Comment: When using your external IP, make sure it's your own and not a NATed IP. Mobile carriers tend to put many users behind a NAT and thus one IP address. In turn it is not possible to reach any device behind that NAT, including your web server.

Comment: @GianTree I guess that is the problem I had when trying the port-forwarding method also... I am pretty sure it os a NATed IP. Would it be possible aomehow to get my own external IP then? Otherwise I don't see why my router has both the port-forwatding and DMZ setting pages... Thanks