# How do I get my public static IP address?

Tags: web-services, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting my IP address?](https://superuser.com/questions/19917/getting-my-ip-address)

I need to use a web service that has blocked public IP addresses. It gives access to only those that are listed on their access list.

I want to test my application in localhost first so I need to put my IP address in that access list and test it in my local server but I don't know my public static IP address.

How can I find it out?

Comment: do you know that your ip address is static? Use e.g. http://whatismyipaddress.com/ to see your current ip. (though if you are testing in locally you might rather want your network ip. check "ipconfig" (win) or "ifconfig" (linux) )

Comment: Do you want to make your software discover the public IP address, or you want to find it manually?

Comment: -1, just searching for "my public IP" on Google will show you the IP address directly. No research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public IP : http://www.whatismyip.com/

Check for open ports : http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: thanks for the link. i used the ip address result shown from the link you provided and it's working..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to search in google: just type the word: ip

The first result will be: Your public IP address is ....

Comment: i did it but the result from other sites such as http://www.whatismyip.com/ is different