# List of pages that return only user's IP address

Tags: internet

Do you know pages that only return user's ip address?

You can use curl to view your address in a console or use it in a script

```
curl http://page
```

Does someone know more?

- http://icanhazip.com/
- http://curlmyip.com/ - @Nicolay
- http://checkip.amazonaws.com - @MyNameIsBoring
- http://ifconfig.me/ip - @MyNameIsBoring (http://ifconfig.me/ contains more online ip utils)

---

Got any idea how to tag it? Online tools or something?

Comment: This one is identical to what you already have - [http://curlmyip.com/](http://curlmyip.com/)

Comment: It's not identical, it has another IP address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting my IP address?](http://superuser.com/questions/19917/getting-my-ip-address)

Comment: "it has another IP address" That's... kinda... weird... (am I the only one thinking that?) If you're a normal home user you have only 1 (that is ONE) IP-address, and unless it's a dynamic one and changes very often, it should be the same, no matter which website you use to check it.

Comment: @nidunc, it is not clear what was meant by `it has another IP address`, so we do not know what is actual "meaning payload" of this statement.

Comment: @Nikolay these pages will die from time to time. That are different sites, that's what I meant.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, now I see what you mean. Well, lets take a look. [icanhazip.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/icanhazip.com) was created in 2009. [curlmyip.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/curlmyip.com) was created in 2011. I think they demonstrated their intention to stay online for long time. And I even would not bother checking [checkip.amazonaws.com](http://whois.domaintools.com/amazonaws.com). Amazon is one of the biggest Internet businesses - they will exist for a while without a doubt.

Comment: More is better nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

When you connect to a website, your web browser hands the server a packet of information about you. This includes your public IP address. Servers such as your example simply repeat this back to the visitor.

Here's how to do it in PHP :

```
<?PHP
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

From:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor

Comment: I asked for page urls, not how to make it. It still can be useful for using it on any free hosting

Comment: Sorry.,, I read your question as "does someone know more about this".  Didn't realize you were asking for additional examples.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use one of these two:

http://ifconfig.me

http://checkip.amazonaws.com

Comment: The first output more that just an IP adress. The second is fine.

Comment: The first one returns just an IP when I curl it.  I've never actually tried it in a browser before.  If you scroll to the bottom of the page it shows links to get other info with curl as well.

Comment: "The first one returns just an IP when I curl it." - True, but probably some day you'll use a client that uses browser user agent string. It's slow too. http://ifconfig.me/ip works