# Can I access my home PC while in office?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, webex, live-meeting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [How to access my Home PC from the office?](https://superuser.com/questions/17911/how-to-access-my-home-pc-from-the-office)

I have my home PC which I want to access while I am in office, something similar to a VNC server/viewer OR a Remote Desktop OR a ssh. Now my home PC has an IP Address = 192.168.1.x and similarly in my office PC also (= 10.232.x.x).

Can I do something?

Comment: Those are you internal IP addresses... Also what kind of access are you looking for? Files? Performing certain tasks?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). It allows you to control your PC over internet, just like Remote Desktop of Windows. It works for Linux, Windows or Mac.

Comment: + TeamViewer. You do not have to care about stuff like port forwarding. The Teamviewer servers even tunnel for you through https if your company network uses a proxy server or restricts all other ports.

Answer (score 3):

Your home PC address of 192.168.x.x is actually the internal IP on your home network. As discussed above, you will need a solution to bridge the gap between web and home PC.

Usually this is done via some kind of [Dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service (either on home PC or running on home router) which broadcasts your external (www) IP address (usually something like 74.125.79.104).

You will then need to [forward the correct ports](http://portforward.com/help/portforwarding.htm) on your home router so it knows to route communications on those ports to your home PC within the network (and open them on home PC firewall).

Answer (score 2):

Citrix does a product called [GoToMyPC](http://www.gotomypc.co.uk/remote_access/remote_access) which does this sort of thing and is very usable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reach your Desktop at home via VNC, SSH or RDP you have to forward the service-specific ports to your Desktop in your home-lan (use static IPs!).
These are the ports that have to be forwarded:

- VNC: tcp 5589
- SSH: tcp 22
- RDP: tcp 3389

Edit: you didn't tell us which OS you're running.
Despite this, there are other ways to control your PC without opening any ports. It could be done with Netviewer, Teamviewer or similar software. These tools connect from your lan to a server and are tunneling the network-traffic from source-pc to target-pc with http-packets.